# List of classes in C#

Tags: c#, class

I have a problem with my code C#.

In the table of database **`Users`** I have users with two tariff plans **`(multitariff)`.**

I need populate my Label **`plane`** with the values of plane extracted from the database to single user.

I thought about to create a **`list of classes`** where stored the values of plane.

I have tried using this solution without success, because the output is only the first value of plane and not all the values of plane for **`multitariff user`**.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Here is my code:

```
string plane;

List<string> planeList = new List<string>();

public class Lists
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> planeList = new List<string>();
    }
}

protected void Users()
{
    using (OdbcConnection cn =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        sql = " SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = ? ";

        using (OdbcCommand command =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", Server.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies["Id"].Value));
                command.Connection.Open();

                using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        plane = reader["plane"].ToString();
                        planeList.Add(plane.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Users();

        if (Request.Cookies["Id"] != null)
        {
            foreach (string plane in planeList)
            {
                plane.Text = "User plane: " + plane.ToString().Trim() + "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by  plane.Text  ??

Comment: @Hamamelis Can you please show the schema of your table with some sample data ?

Comment: You are reading a column from 1 record ("plane" from user with a specific Id), but somehow you expect to read several values from that column... Can you show us the structure of your User table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of your label everytime:

```
foreach (string plane in planeList)
{
    plane.Text = "User plane: " + plane.ToString().Trim() + "<br />";
}
```

Instead of overwriting it you should concatenate the string:

```
plane.Text = "User plane: ";
foreach (string item in planeList)
{
    plane.Text += item.ToString().Trim() + "<br />"; // I suppose plane is a label here, so your foreach variable should be called different (item in this case)
}
```